# Syntax to create a dynamic string in PHP

Tags: php, html

I am going cross-eyed trying to figure out my syntax error here.

I have a table that I create dynamically.  The user can click on one cell in a row to get an alert with notes in it.

The problem is that my quote marks are incorrect no matter what I do.  I'm obviously not seeing something.

This PHP code

```
"<td onclick='showNotes()' ></td>";
```

Gets me in my HTML code upon rendering

```
<td onclick="showNotes()"></td>
```

This looks good and executes my jQuery no problem.  So far so good.

========================================================

This PHP code (where $col contains the notes to be displayed)

```
"<td onclick='showNotes(" . $col . ")' ></td>";
```

gets me this in my HTML

```
<td onclick="showNotes(myNewNotes)"></td>
```

The only problem here is that myNewNotes is a string and needs to have quotes around it, or else I get an error that it is not defined.  OK, moving along.

========================================================

So now I try this PHP code

```
"<td onclick='showNotes(" . "'" . $col . "'" . "')' ></td>";
```

Which gets me this in the HTML, which is crap.

```
<td onclick="showNotes(" myNewNotes'')'></td>
```

=========================================================

WHAT is going on?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can escape quotes within your string, which will get you what you need:

```
"<td onclick='showNotes(\"$col\")' ></td>";
```

Comment: YES!  Thank you so much.

Answer (score 0):

Normally you should use escape \ this way

```
  "<td onclick='showNotes(\'" .  $col ."\');' ></td>";
```

Answer (score 0):

How about this

```
    echo "td onclick='showNotes(" .'"'. $col .'"'. ")' ></td>";
```